# Tampermonkey/GreaseMonkey Auto Click Button

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I was wondering if anyone could help me create JavaScript for Tampermonkey on Chrome that will create button for click another button

And here is the js path for the button:

```js
document.querySelector("#root > div.sc-jtiXyc.jireel > div:nth-child(1) > div.product > div.container > div.create-listing > div.create-listing-btn-bar > button")
```

```js
(function() {
  function add() {
    document.querySelector("#root > div.sc-jtiXyc.jireel > div:nth-child(1) > div.product > div.container > div.create-listing > div.create-listing-btn-bar > button").click();
  }

  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  btn.innerHTML = "Add to listing";
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
  document.querySelector("body > button").style.position = "fixed";
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    add();
  });
})();
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `yourButton.click()`?

Comment: when i try it, it's not working

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

`.click()` works. Make sure your tampermonkey script starts after the document has loaded and your queryselector is correct.

```js
(() => {
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerText = "I'm the second button";
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("you clicked the second button");
    document.querySelector("button#og").click();
  });
  document.body.appendChild(button);
})()
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log('you clicked the og button')" id="og">
  OG Button
</button>
```